# NPM module installation error

Tags: node.js, proxy, nodes

I am getting Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND while trying to install a module in node.js. It seems some proxy error.I checked in browser setting ,proxy is disabled. But when i am checking in command prompt  npm config get proxy, getting 192.168.98.5:8080. How to disable this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, try to execute `npm config delete proxy`. If you get something like `Error: ENOENT, unlink '/Users/drlazor/.npmrc'` is OK; that means you don't have a npm config file and, therefore, no proxy settings.

Second, verify you have no proxy settings with `npm config get proxy`. You should get a `null`or the above error. If you keep on getting a result different from `null`, you should also ensure you haven't set the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`.

Third and last, if none of those worked, try accessing the URL from your browser; it could be a network issue after all.

Comment: "npm config set proxy null" was the best way for me to remove the proxy completely, as there is a default value for the proxy for some reason.

Comment: wiped out the proxy settings in here and all is working. thank you!

Comment: cool ! set both proxy settings to null...worked for me ..Amazing solution.. spent hours to get to resolve

Comment: You can also get this error if the environment variable HTTP_PROXY is set and you are not working behind an HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 5):

You should check the [npm](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html) config page on how to set and modify config values. proxy key stores proxy server to use to connect to npm repositories. Try this :

```
npm config delete proxy
```

Answer (score 5):

**Note: This Works if you are not behind a Proxy i.e (From a Personal Computer)**

First execute this command

```
npm config edit
```

npm the configuration file opens
comment following two lines in the opened file by putting **";"(semi Colon)** in start of the line.

`npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`
`npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

You are done.
Now install any package you want to.

```
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g npm
```

or anything else you need to install

Comment: Even after executing `npm config delete https-proxy` I was having issues. Then I tried `npm config edit` & to my suprise the https-proxy was still set! Removing it sorted out the issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i was in the same state and got this error because of the wrong proxy value format
(i just miss "http://" at the beginning of the proxies values).

If a proxy should be set, here is the format (values depend of your network) :

> npm config set proxy http://proxy.mydomain:3128
>
> npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.mydomain:3128

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if your NPM is configured to use a different NPM registry server (possibly you are on a work machine and not connected to the network/VPN). To see if this is the case:

```
npm config edit
```

and look for:

```
registry=http://alternateurl
```

The default is:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

You can connect to your VPN/network or change that config to correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all 3 proxy

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.name.xx:port
npm config set http-proxy http://proxy.name.xx:port
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.name.xx:port
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no proxy use the following commands:

```
npm config delete https-proxy
npm config delete proxy
```

if you are using a proxy use:

```
npm config set proxy $PROXY
npm config set http-proxy $PROXY
```

Either of the two tend to work

Answer (score 0):

In case setting proxy via terminal or creating **.npmrc** does not help, try to put **.typingsrc** file in c:\Users\'username' with the following content

```
{
  "proxy": "http://proxy.name.xx:port",
  "https-proxy": "http://proxy.name.xx:port",
  "strict-ssl": false
}
```