# Error in npm install socket.io in node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I installed my node js on windows service pack 2.
When I tried to run npm install socket.io it is giving error as [image: here].

I want to mention that I'm not installing it in my system admin mode.

Help me.

Comment: What happens when you navigate to https://registry.npmjs.org/ in a browser on this machine?  What does `node --version` and `npm --version` report?

Answer (score 0):

[NPM module installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569755/npm-module-installation-error)
[nodejs module npm install error / gcm-node module send err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509252/nodejs-module-npm-install-error-gcm-node-module-send-err)

Those links seems to provide some pointers/answers, might be useful to check them out.