# sudo npm install -g ionic error

Tags: ionic-framework

MacBooks-MacBook-Pro:~ Apple$ sudo npm install -g ionic
Password:
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Apple
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Apple/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: Did this helped? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569755/npm-module-installation-error

Comment: have you installed node.js library first

Answer (score 0):

Try installing without `sudo`

`npm install -g ionic`

If that does not help there is an existing Github issue about proxies:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3354

You might also try this Stack Overflow question:

[Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)